# Blender mesh move not corectly in Pose Mode despite WeightPaint and Removing Doubls

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

My mesh or the belt of my character is not moved properly with, in spite of Weight Paint and removing Doubles/ merge by distance.

My Mesh;
[image]

My Mesh when i pose and you can see that my belt ist destroyed:
[image]

My mesh is weight Painted:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to Normalize? While in Weight paint mode go to *Weights > Normalize All*.

Maybe there is another bone that is influencing that area for some reason and is causing the distortion.